# Ordering frequency of qualitative data by rank

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set where the ranks of military personnel are outlined according to their response to a survey. I can produce the frequency table from a pandas series using value_counts() but I want to produce a cumulative frequency or percentile table, and for that to be meaningful, I have to order the frequency data according to the ranks, from highest ranked officer to lowest ranked officer and then deduce their percentile responses using the ranks. Please, can someone show me how to do this? I am stumped. I know how to do the cumulative frequency using pandas cumsum() but it doesn't order according to rank. How do I order the output of a value_count() according to specified rank? thanks

Comment: [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

Comment: You can use [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with a dictionary of rank to ordinal number, do value counts, then by reversing the dictionary map the ordinal numbers in the index back to ranks. For more specific help, please [edit] your question with some sample input and output, and code for what you've tried, to make a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks, G. Anderson. I followed your instructions but couldn't reverse the dictionary mapping, so I just did a hack. I renamed the indexes and that was that. I appreciate.